# How disk and cache scheduling implement for GPEG and MPEG Standard

Tags: operating-system

i am working on Operating system theory assignment and stuck on a question that **how disk and cache scheduling implement for GPEG and MPEG standar**

Comment: Well, have you read the standards?

Comment: You're a little big vague here. I presume that you want to have a cache that is optimized for MPEG. When you hit some part of the stream, you want to pull in the rest of the stream and possibly discard those parts already played.